# Preventing hot linking of all files without .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cgi

Well, i have a slight problem. I basically own a file sharing website and am having problems with people hot linking files

I have tried .htaccess with no luck as i want to redirect the hot linking to the download page where the actual file is.

I have seen other sites do this, but i am confused how they do it.

Some use cgi-bin scripts, but i am equally not sure how this is done.

Does anyone have a clue what the best practice is to do this?

Comment: Why not use `.htaccess`? This could be done with a PHP script, too, but a .htaccess file would be vastly superior

Comment: Files are held on remote servers, how would i go about this.

Comment: How are you accessing those remote servers from your webserver?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script that reads the file on the webserver and outputs the data to the client. In that script you can verify the origin by checking the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` value.

Small example for outputting a file:

```
<?php
$filename = "file";
$filesize = filesize($filename);
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$data = fread($handle, $filesize);
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-length: " . $filesize);
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=" . $filename);
echo $data;
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: All files are stored on remote file servers, does this still make a difference?

Comment: If the link to the file on the remote server is invisible to your visitors, they will not be able to hotlink them

Comment: The source will be your PHP script, not the actual file. The PHP script will act as a proxy to the file data

Comment: Now I think of it, if your files are hosted on an external fileserver that can not be accessed over the LAN by the webserver, this method will be useless, because you will create a lot of traffic over the internet and will soon run out of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Never let users see the actual path oftheactual file. Instead, serve it to them via a php script, and check against a session to make sure they went through ask the necessary steps before serving then their files.

Comment: And files are stored on remote servers, this still possible?

Comment: How is hotlinking different than you redirecting users to a different server to get your files? The script to serve the files should be on the same server as the files.

Comment: True that, should i use a simple PHP file or something like CGI, Perl or Ruby